# How can I upload array of files using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, multer

Have been trying to upload multiple images with multer array upload but they are not displaying in my index page  but using single.upload() is working fine and displaying the images .

/ Set The Storage Engine

```
  destination: './public/upload',
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

// Init Upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits:{
    fileSize: 100000000
  },
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
});

// Check File Type
function checkFileType(file, cb){

  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;

   // Check ext
   const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

   // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null,true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Images Only!');
  }

Var upload = multer({storage: storage})

router.post("/", upload.array('image'),(req, res) => {

    const newSell= new Sell({
   year: req.body.year,
  text: req.body.text,
  image:'/upload/'+req.files
    });

    newSell.save().then(sell => res.json(sell));
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(req.files)`?

Comment: When I console log am getting the files but it's not displaying in the upload folder and frontend